# how convert string \\u6d4e\\u5357\\u5e02 to utf-8 data

Tags: c

gcc will format `\u6d4e\u5357\u5e02` to utf-8 encoding data. But how can i format ucs2 string to utf-8 encoding data?

```
    char str[] = "\\u6d4e\\u5357\\u5e02";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a converter function.

```
/* Input: a Unicode code point, "ucs2". 

   Output: UTF-8 characters in buffer "utf8". 

   Return value: the number of bytes written into "utf8", or a
   negative number if there was an error.

   This adds a zero byte to the end of the string. It assumes that the
   buffer "utf8" has at least four bytes of space to write to. */

int ucs2_to_utf8 (int ucs2, unsigned char * utf8)
{
    if (ucs2 < 0x80) {
        utf8[0] = ucs2;
        utf8[1] = '\0';
        return 1;
    }
    if (ucs2 >= 0x80  && ucs2 < 0x800) {
        utf8[0] = (ucs2 >> 6)   | 0xC0;
        utf8[1] = (ucs2 & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        utf8[2] = '\0';
        return 2;
    }
    if (ucs2 >= 0x800 && ucs2 < 0xFFFF) {
    if (ucs2 >= 0xD800 && ucs2 <= 0xDFFF) {
        /* Ill-formed. */
        return UNICODE_SURROGATE_PAIR;
    }
        utf8[0] = ((ucs2 >> 12)       ) | 0xE0;
        utf8[1] = ((ucs2 >> 6 ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        utf8[2] = ((ucs2      ) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        utf8[3] = '\0';
        return 3;
    }
    if (ucs2 >= 0x10000 && ucs2 < 0x10FFFF) {
    /* http://tidy.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/lxr/source/src/utf8.c#L380 */
    utf8[0] = 0xF0 | (ucs2 >> 18);
    utf8[1] = 0x80 | ((ucs2 >> 12) & 0x3F);
    utf8[2] = 0x80 | ((ucs2 >> 6) & 0x3F);
    utf8[3] = 0x80 | ((ucs2 & 0x3F));
        utf8[4] = '\0';
        return 4;
    }
    return UNICODE_BAD_INPUT;
}
```

[Refer to this page](http://www.lemoda.net/c/ucs2-to-utf8/)